# Better user switching for Windows XP?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I like the way Mac OS switches users (e.g. a dropdown at the top left of the screen).  Is there such a thing for Windows XP?  Because the way it's currently implemented on Windows XP (and Vista/Win7) is a real hassle involving a dozen clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The current user doesn't have to be logged off?**

Else use Windows+L to select a different user

**The user has to be logged off?**

Use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to make Windows+L log off your current user

**Fast user switching?**

If you have to type user names you should enable [Fast User Switching](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/accessibility/fastuserswitching.mspx) to give the icons for each users instead